# Handle latest values ​by group - Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I needed to sum up the most recent values ​​per person, I found the last date function which resolves that part of the recent value. But it only takes the most recent value from everyone, how do I segment this by group?

I'm putting a print of an example table and when trying to get the most recent value if the category is radar it returns 8 (which is not wrong)

But I wanted it to return 16, most recent 8 from one person with the most recent 8 from another for radar category.

Example:
Person Grade Tool Date

P1      10    X    march/2021

P1      7     X    feb/2022

P2      9     X    august/2021

Expected result is 16 (7 recent for P1 + 9 recent for p2)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what you want but if you had a table like this loaded into Powerqery,

[image]

then you could find the most recent 8 dates for each [Person/Type] combination using this code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Person", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"amount", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Person", "Type"}, {{"data", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}}),8), type table }}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Top8", each List.Sum([data][amount]))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

and wind up with

[image]

You could add column, custom column, with formula

```
= List.Sum(#"Added Custom"[Top8])
```

to get a grand total of all the 8 most recent days

**UPDATE:**

If you just want the max date then single step filter as follows:

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStepName", each ([Date] = List.Max( #"PriorStepName"[Date])))
```

And get a single cell grand total after that with

```
Total=List.Sum(#"PriorStepName2"[amount])
```

Comment: I want to sum the most recent values by Person and Type, in your table expected result is 3, 0 from p1 x and 3 from p2 x

Comment: You want to filter all the data for the most recent date and then after that sum the amount?  see updated code

Comment: did that work for you?